# Information and examples of interaction between threads and continuations in Scheme?

Tags: multithreading, scheme, continuations

I've been using SRFI 18 in different Scheme implementations (Gambit, Gauche and Chicken), and I'd like to know where to find dpcumentation/tutorials /information about the problems that may arise when one uses continuations inside threads? 
I suppose there are lots of issues, like what happens if a thread invokes a continuation that was captured by another thread -- either inside or outside `dynamic-wind`, and so on.

Not just a specification (like the SRFI itself), but tips and code examples, examples of how these issues are dealt with in usual programs.

Is there something like that somewhere?

Answer (score 2):

You will not find anything like that for *Scheme*, because there are no threads in the standard specification.  To make things worse, there will probably be some major differences between implementations because some thread implementations use continuation and some use a more native approach.  (For example, Racket falls in the latter category, and in some cases you can "migrate" continuations between threads.)

Comment: "there are no threads in the standard specification" -- yes, but there is a SRFI (18) describing it, and a few Scheme implementations support it...

Comment: "Support" for that srfi can be questionable, but if you know about it, then you can just read it -- carefully.  It does have a section about continuations and dynamic-winds etc.